# Evaluate limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left (\frac 1x- \frac 1{\sin x} \right )$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone provide me with some hint how to evaluate this limit?
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left (\frac 1x- \frac 1{\sin x} \right )
$$
I tried l'hopital's rule but it didn't work.

Comment: Hint, combine the fractions (common denominator), then you can L'H.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400541/find-the-limit-without-use-of-lhopital-or-taylor-series-lim-limits-x-right

Comment: See [What is the result of $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}(1/x - 1/\sin x)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94864/what-is-the-result-of-lim-limits-x-to-01-x-1-sin-x)

Answer (score 7):

The limit would be $\infty-\infty$ when $x\to0$.

As Amzoti have said in the comment, we can combine the fractions and get:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x\sin x},\text{now we can apply L'Hospital's Rule since the limit would be }\frac{0}{0} \\ \\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{\sin x+x\cos x}\\ \\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\sin x}{\cos x+\cos x-x\sin x}\\ \\
&=\boxed{0}
\end{align}

Comment: Use `\sin` instead of `sin`.

Comment: If you put `$\sin x$` instead of `$sin x$`, you'll get the more "operator-looking" $\sin x$. Also, you should have $-x\sin x$ in your last denominator, rather than $-x\cos x$.

Comment: I've corrected it, thanks for the tip!  Learned something new in $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the difference as (after Maclaurin series expansion and some algebra)
$$
\frac{\sin x-x}{x \sin x}=\frac{x+O(x^3)-x}{x(x+O(x^3))}
=\frac{O(x)}{1+O(x^2)}$$
which tends to $0$.